# share only portion of screen on external monitor

Tags: external-monitor

Is there a way in Ubuntu (20.04) under Gnome to share only a portion of the main screen, e.g. the upper left corner, on an external monitor?

Comment: here's maybe a workaround for you
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163841/how-to-share-portion-of-screen-on-a-large-monitor

Comment: @snydex: Thanks, but that one didn't work for me (I added a comment there).